# Can I specify class namespace with method definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does python support class namespace specification in a method definition. As in

```
class Student(self):
   def Student::getName(self):
       blah blah ..
```

Leveraging presentation (tabs and such) is proving a bit problematic. For example, try to move a large method (over 200 lines) with lots of indentations to another file.

Perhaps this can be solved with a decorator of sort

Comment: I think the fact that you have a method of over 200 is a bad idea and it should be broken down to more methods. But also, if it is a class method, you should copy it to another file within its class, so where is the problem?

Comment: Well, you could define the function anywhere and then assign it into the class: `Student.getName = getName`.  But that's far worse than the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: No, Python does not. But you accomplish the same thing to some degree by doing what @jasonharper suggests.

Comment: I inherited the code...the other guy did not believe in short func defs.
Consider this code
```
1 #!/usr/bin/python3
  2 
  3 class A:
  4     def __init__(self):
  5         print("In A")
  6     class B:
  7         def __init__(self):
  8             print("In B")
  9         class C:
 10             def __init__(self):
 11                 print("In C")
 12 
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following nested class definitions

```
1 #!/usr/bin/python3
  2 
  3 class A:
  4     def __init__(self):
  5         print("In A")
  6     class B:
  7         def __init__(self):
  8             print("In B")
  9         class C:
 10             def __init__(self):
 11                 print("In C")
 12
```